# unix expr command shows strange results comparing integers

Tags: unix, shell

When I  write

```
expr 123 \< 5
```

the result is correct (0) because expr evaluates two integers.
Also

```
expr 123. \< 5
```

gives the expected result (1) because now it compares two strings.
But

```
expr "123" \< 5
```

gives 0 (I expected 1, as before)
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr 123 \< 5
```

and

```
expr "123" \< 5
```

give the same answer because what the `expr` command sees in its program arguments is exactly the same in both cases.  Arguments 1, 2, and 3 are `123`, `<`, and `5` in both cases.

Use `/bin/echo` instead of `expr` to see this more clearly.

Escaping and quoting are *handled by your shell*.  What commands see once run is what your command line ends up as *after* the shell has handled all redirections, expansions, and subtitutions, and removed all quoting.